# Issues with eclipse connecting with Github

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I am trying to connect my java eclipse project to github and I am having a metadata.lock issue. When I share my project and specify a git initialized folder I get the following error

```
Failed to initialize Git team provider.
Problems encountered while moving resources.
Could not move '/MDKExample'.
Could not move: C:\Users\Orange1861\Dropbox\[project name].
Could not read from source when writing file: C:\Users\Orange1861\Dropbox\[project name]\eclipse\.metadata\.lock
The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file
```

which stops the transfer and breaks the original project, while I made a backup right before I tried this so nothing was lost, I can't seem to connect the two.

Comment: can't you just ignore this .metadata file ?

Comment: There is no ignore button and it then skips everything that comes after it, including the src folder.